# Error al Implementar FireBase en proyecto Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, build.gradle

Estoy iniciando un proyecto en Android Studio. Pero, cuando intento implementar FireBase me da un error al sincronizar los `build.gradle` :

A continuación les dejo el error que me sale en la consola:

> org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.TupleExpression cannot be cast to org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ArgumentListExpression
> org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.TupleExpression cannot be cast to org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ArgumentListExpression
>
> Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
>
> Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
> The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
>
> Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
> Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.
>
> In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

He intentado reiniciando Android Studio y al parecer se arregla el error, pero cuando compilo la aplicación, me vuelve a dar el mismo error. También he intentado borrando ese proyecto y empezando otro, pero sale el mismo error.

Si alguien sabe como resolverlo agradecería su apoyo. Gracias

### **Edit**

Agrego el codigo que tengo en los 2 build.gradle.

Build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all 
sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Build.gradle (Modulo App)

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.goart.goart"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android- 
optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
}

dependencies {

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.1.0')

}
```

Comment: Un poco raro, la clase que muestra el error es de Grovy,  me parece que tienes dependencias que no son soportadas en Android, te sugiero agregar tu Build.gradle.

Comment: Listo he añadido en la publicacion los codigos de ambos Build.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

En Build.gradle (Modulo App)
cambia
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

por

id 'com.google.gms.google-services'

eso me soluciono el error

Answer (score 0):

Yo arregle de la siguiente forma, cambié

**Build.gradle (Modulo App)**

```
    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    }
```

por

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```